# Program quits out after running?

Tags: c, file, memory-leaks

The program runs fine and displays the data I want but then crashes. I don't think it is a memory leak from the linked list because I've tried many ways to free it and none have worked.

```
#include "Buildings.h"

void displayBuilding(struct node *x){
    printf("Building Name: %s\n\tFloors: %d\n\tValue: %d\n\n", x->payload.name, x->payload.floors, x->payload.value);
    if(x->last!=1){
        displayBuilding(x->next);
    }
}

void insert(struct node *x, char str[50]){
    srand(t);
    int f = (rand() % 6)+1;
    int v = ((rand() % 20)+1)*f;
    //printf("Floors: %d and Value: %d\n", f, v);
    strcpy(x->payload.name, str);
    x->payload.floors = f;
    x->payload.value = v;
    srand(time(NULL));
    t+=f+v*(rand()%1000);
}

FILE* openData(FILE *f){
    f = fopen("Buildings-Data.txt", "r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("No File!");
        return 0;
    }
    return f;
}

void freeList(struct node* head)
{
   struct node* tmp;

   while (head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(tmp);
    }

}

int main(){
    FILE *f1;
    struct node *head;
    struct node *curr;
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    curr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    curr = head;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        curr->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    f1 = openData(f1);
    curr = head;
    int readNum;
    char trash;
    fscanf(f1, "%d", &readNum);
    fscanf(f1, "%c", &trash);
    for(i=0;i<readNum;i++){
        char str[50];
        fscanf(f1, "%s",str);
        insert(curr, str);
        curr->last = 0;
        if(readNum-i==1){
            curr->last = 1;
        }else{
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    fscanf(f1, "%c", &trash);
    fclose(f1);
    curr = head;
    printf("\n");
    displayBuilding(curr);

    curr = head;
    freeList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

My header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct building{
    char name[50];
    int floors;
    int value;  
};
typedef struct building place;

struct node{
    place payload;
    struct node *next;
    int last;
};

int t = 500;
```

Comment: Comment out 'freeList(head);'.  Now what happens?

Comment: It's Debugging 101:  'if in doubt, comment it out'.

Comment: Note that it is not a good idea to use global variables in general, and doubly so not a good idea to use single-letter names for global variables, and it is absolutely a bad idea to initialize a global variable in a header because it means only one source file in a program can use the header, and there's no point in creating a header if only one source file will ever use it.

Comment: You have a memory leak because you first set `curr = malloc();`, and then immediately after that you do `curr = head`. So you've leaked the memory that you originally assigned to `curr`. But memory leaks don't cause crashes.

Comment: @MartinJames that worked and allowed the program to finish! Any thoughts as to why that was halting it?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you shouldn't call `srand()` every time you call `insert()`. Do it once at the beginning of the program.

Comment: @Barmar in relation to your comment about `srand()` I have that to allow the seed to change. When I had it seed just once in relation to time the random numbers were all the same.

Comment: How many buildings are in the file? You're only allocating 9 items in your linked list. If there are more buildings, you'll go past the end of the list.

Comment: You invoke `srand()` twice each time you use `insert()` — that's bad.  See [`srand()` — why call it only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once/) for the details.  It seems funny to preload 10 empty records into the list.  The whole dynamic of reading records into the 'list' needs to be reviewed.  And you probably need to check for more null pointers.

Comment: @GeorgeTangen a bug in freeList() or an invalid 'head' argument.  Debugger time!

Comment: @MartinJames `freeList()` looks pretty good to me. I suspect something else is causing undefined behavior before he calls it, and memory is getting corrupted.

Comment: @Barmar yes, good point, also very possible;)  Given the number of bugs already commented on above, you could even say 'likely' :(

Comment: @Barmar I don't see anywhere that the head is ever set to NULL, 'head = malloc(sizeof(struct node))',  so 'while (head != NULL)' seems like a bad plan:(

Comment: @MartinJames `head = head->next` is supposed to do that, except for the problem that I point out in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar I was getting there, albeit slowly.  Anyway, have an upboat for firsties:)

Comment: @MartinJames If you intended that as a clue to the OP, you're living in a dreamland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you create the linked list, you never set `next` to `NULL` in the last node of the list. You need to do that after the loop:

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    curr->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    curr = curr->next;
}
curr->next = NULL;
```

Because of this, the `while (head != NULL)` loop in `freeList()` never stops, and eventually tries to free the uninitialized pointer in the last node of the list.